# Adding js to wordpress for css activemenu highlight

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

I want to add a simple highlight to my active menus in wordpress.
To do this I have this i have tracked down some pieces of code that might be useful (if they worked.) I am a complete rookie when it comes to js, but i know so much as to put this snippet of code inside my functions.php

```
// Enqueue JavaScripts
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('cartrawler', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js', array(), '20120802', '1');
    wp_enqueue_script('cartrawler', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js', array(), '20120802', '1');
    wp_enqueue_script('cartrawler', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/activemenu.js', array(), '30120802', '1');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts');
```

I have refered to this link in helping me out on the small script that makes this possible:
http://jsfiddle.net/K6F8m/

Comment: I know i have no need for colorbox, but I thought I might have a need for it down the road :)

Comment: Most themes and theme frameworks do this automagically :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `wp_enqueue_script` line is bad.  You're using a fully qualified URL (`https://ajax.googleapis.com...`) but preceding it with your theme's URL.  Try replacing the first `wp_enqueue_script` line with:

```
wp_enqueue_script('cartrawler', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js', array(), '20120802', '1');
```

If that doesn't fix your problem outright, please elaborate on what the actual problem you're having is.  Are the scripts not showing up in the HTML?  Are they in the HTML but not working?

Answer (score 1):

If you create your menu using the function wp_nav_menu() function Wordpress automatically adds classes that allow you to create the "active menu highlight" effect that you are looking for.

A few of these classes are `.current-menu-item`, `.current-menu-parent`, `.current-{object}-parent`, `.current-{type}-parent`, etc.

Here is the [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Comment: What if i have previously made a working menu on top of a sandbox theme, and i want to keep that menu? Can i still implement it, and how?

Here's how the site looks right now.
http://www.lufter.dk/test/wordpress/?page_id=21

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to use your sandbox theme (with the menu) to be incorporated into your new theme?  If so you should research the parent-child theme relationship.  You can create your new theme as a child to your sandbox theme.  This way your menu will automatically be loaded (i assume in the sandboxes functions.php file.)

 [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so by looking a bit more upon the DOM I noticed that wordpress has already made a class for unknown menu items:

```
div#menu li.current_page_item a{
color:#000;
}
div#menu li.current_page_item a:hover{
color:#662D91;
}
```

My problem now is that all the children of that parent also becomes highlighted in black, when I enter the parent page. :( I can't remember how to fix this!!